# PHP debugging in VSCode - Breakpoints ignored in Firefox when debugging code on my NAS

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, vscode-debugger

This my first post on stackoverflow.com, so please be kind with me. ;-) I have spent many hours searching for an answer on the internet but have not found one which exactly answers my question.

## My goal / expected result

I want to debug PHP code on the webserver on my NAS (DiskStation) via Firefox Dev browser on Debian. I want to be able to set breakpoints and see the variable values and the output of the page up to that breakpoint. However, Firefox is always loading the complete page and VSCodium doesn’t stop at my breakpoints. When debugging with the PHP-CLI version installed locally on my laptop breakpoints are hit and variable values shown, but then I’m not seeing the updated version of my website in Firefox.

## My environment / What I’ve done

I have VSCodium 1.63.2 installed on Debian 11 and want to debug PHP on my local Synology DiskStation running a web server with Apache 2.4.46, PHP 7.4.18 and Xdebug 2.9.6 (currently there are no newer versions available via official packages) on port 9003.

I have installed the following extensions in VSCodium:

- PHP Debug by Felix Becker: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug
- Debugger for Firefox (although I believe this is primarily for debugging JavaScript): https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=firefox-devtools.vscode-firefox-debug

I have also installed PHP with Xdebug locally on my laptop (without any webserver) and this CLI version is working as expected (see below, I set it to port 9004).

But firstly, here’s the complete *launch.json* for my project:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "url": "http://ds/st4/index.php",
            "file": "http://ds/st4/index.php",
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "remoteRoot": "/var/services/web/st4",
            "reAttach": true,
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Firefox Dev",
            "type": "firefox",
            "firefoxExecutable": "/opt/firefox-dev/firefox",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 6002,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "url": "http://ds/st4/index.php",
            "file": "http://ds/st4/index.php",
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "remoteRoot": "/var/services/web/st4",
            "reAttach": true,
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "url": "http://ds",
                    "path": "/mnt/web"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Local PHP-CLI",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9004,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have configured PHP and Xdebug on my DiskStation as follows:

```ini
output_buffering=Off
xdebug.idekey=vsc
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

For testing purposes I then set two random breakpoints in my project. They are in lines 5 and 9 (as you can see in the following picture):

[image: Screenshot: breakpoints set before starting debugging in VSCodium]

### Local PHP-CLI respects my breakpoints (working as intended)

When I use the **‚Local PHP-CLI‘ config** to debug my project (see *launch.json* file above), everything is working as expected. The breakpoints are hit and (as you can see in the top right corner of the next screenshot) I can use all of the debug tools like ‚Step Over‘, ‚Step Into‘ etc. So, on the first breakpoint the debug console in VSCodium shows „1“, on the second breakpoint it’s „123“ and at the end the output is „1234“ - as expected according to the test in my index.php (see picture above). Also, the values of the variables are shown on the left-hand side in VSCodium.

[image: Screenshot: breakpoints being hit when debugging with local PHP-CLI]

### ‚Debugger for Firefox‘ doesn’t stop at breakpoints

However, when I try to debug in my browser (Firefox Developer Edition 97) with the help of the ‚Debugger for Firefox‘ extension in VSCodium, breakpoints are not hit and no variable values are displayed in VSCodium.
The Xdebug helper addon for Firefox is enabled and set to ‚Debug‘ (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xdebug-helper-for-firefox/).

So, what I’m doing is I start debugging in VSCodium with the **‚Firefox Dev‘ config** (see *launch.json* file above). Before that, I have already opened Firefox Developer Edition. As soon as I hit debugging in VSCodium, a new tab with the project’s index.php opens (http://ds/st4/index.php).  The debugger seems to be connected to Firefox, but the page is loading entirely, displaying „1234“. Locally the files can be accessed via samba and are mounted in */mnt/web/st4/index.php* – that’s why I mapped this path in my *launch.json* file.

*When debugging with 'Debugger for Firefox' extension in VSCodium breakpoints are not hit and debug tool icons like ‚Step Over‘, ‚Step Into‘ are greyed out (top-right corner):*

[image: Screenshot: When debugging with 'Debugger for Firefox' extension in VSCodium breakpoints are not hit and debug tool icons like ‚Step Over‘, ‚Step Into‘ are greyed out (top-right corner)]

### ‚Listen for Xdebug‘ also doesn’t respect breakpoints in Firefox

For your information, I have started Firefox Dev with the following arguments to start the debugging server on port 6002 – according to my *launch.json* config: `/opt/firefox-dev/firefox --start-debugger-server 6002 %u`

So, when I start the **‚Listen for Debug‘ config** from my *launch.json* nothing happens - which is, I believe, normal. As soon as I reload the project’s index.php (http://ds/st4/index.php) the breakpoints disappear in VSCodium, but the page is, again, loading completely without stopping at any breakpoint and no variable values are shown in VSCodium.
When I disconnect/stop debugging in VSCodium (hitting the ‚Stop‘ button from the debug tools bar), the breakpoints are greyed out (a circle with a grey outline, see picture below). When I mouseover these breakpoints, it says ***‚Unverified Breakpoint‘***.

[image: Screenshot: When debugging via 'Listen for debug' breakpoints are also not hit, but greyed out, saying 'Unverified Breakpoint']

What I found when searching for this problem is that a possible reason could be that the local and remote paths are not correctly mapped / the file on the local or remote server cannot be found. But I can’t use the ***"pathMappings"*** section in the ‚Listen for Debug‘ config because VSCodium would mark it as wrong syntax even though I checked it more than once for any mistakes. This setting seems to work only in the *'firefox dev'* config of type *'firefox'*.

**To conclude, my question is:** Is there anything wrong with my configuration in VSCodium or with Xdebug? Or is it normal that breakpoints are ignored when debugging via the browser? Thank you so much in advance!

---

## Edit:

Here's my slightly changed *index.php* for testing purposes:

```
  <?php
    #Testing...
    $i = 1;
    echo $i;
    $i++;
    echo $i;
    $i++;
    echo $i;
    $i++;
    echo $i;
    $i++;
    echo $i;

...
```

I set two breakpoints in VSCodium - in lines 4 and 10. In VSCodium the current values of the variables are shown when stopping at the breakpoints ("1" on line 4 and "4" on line 10).

Still, Firefox is only reloading the new page after debugging has finished (then showing "12345"). The Xdebug helper add-on in Firefox is set to 'Debug'.

My understanding is that Firefox should show "1" when stopping on line 4 and "1234" on line 10, like the local PHP-CLI debugger does in the 'Output' tab in VSCodium when used.

Here's the output of my *xdebug.log* :

```
[6366] Log opened at 2022-01-26 19:43:27
[6366] I: Checking remote connect back address.
[6366] I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[6366] I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[6366] I: Remote address found, connecting to 192.168.1.47:9003.
[6366] I: Connected to client. :-)
[6366] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///volume1/st/st4/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.4.18" protocol_version="1.0" appid="6366" idekey="vsc"><engine version="2.9.6"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2020 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[6366] <- feature_get -i 1 -n resolved_breakpoints
[6366] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_get" transaction_id="1" feature_name="resolved_breakpoints" supported="1"><![CDATA[0]]></response>

[6366] <- feature_set -i 2 -n resolved_breakpoints -v 1
[6366] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="resolved_breakpoints" success="1"></response>

[6366] <- feature_get -i 3 -n notify_ok
[6366] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_get" transaction_id="3" feature_name="notify_ok" supported="1"><![CDATA[0]]></response>

[6366] <- feature_set -i 4 -n notify_ok -v 1
[6366] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" feature="notify_ok" success="1"></response>

[6366] <- feature_get -i 5 -n extended_properties
[6366] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_get" transaction_id="5" feature_name="extended_properties" supported="1"><![CDATA[0]]></response>

[6366] <- feature_set -i 6 -n extended_properties -v 1
[6366] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="6" feature="extended_properties" success="1"></response>

[6366] <- breakpoint_set -i 7 -t line -f file:///volume1/st/st4/index.php -n 4
[6366] D: R: Line number (4) in smallest range of range (1-57)
[6366] D: F: Breakpoint line (4) found in set of executable lines
[6366] -> <notify xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" name="breakpoint_resolved"><breakpoint type="line" resolved="resolved" filename="file:///volume1/st/st4/index.php" lineno="4" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="63660005"></breakpoint></notify>

[6366] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="7" id="63660005" resolved="resolved"></response>

[6366] <- breakpoint_get -i 8 -d 63660005
[6366] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_get" transaction_id="8"><breakpoint type="line" resolved="resolved" filename="file:///volume1/st/st4/index.php" lineno="4" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="63660005"></breakpoint></response>

[6366] <- breakpoint_set -i 9 -t line -f file:///volume1/st/st4/index.php -n 10
[6366] D: R: Line number (10) in smallest range of range (1-57)
[6366] D: F: Breakpoint line (10) found in set of executable lines
[6366] -> <notify xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" name="breakpoint_resolved"><breakpoint type="line" resolved="resolved" filename="file:///volume1/st/st4/index.php" lineno="10" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="63660006"></breakpoint></notify>

[6366] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="9" id="63660006" resolved="resolved"></response>

[6366] <- breakpoint_get -i 10 -d 63660006
[6366] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_get" transaction_id="10"><breakpoint type="line" resolved="resolved" filename="file:///volume1/st/st4/index.php" lineno="10" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="63660006"></breakpoint></response>

[6366] <- run -i 11
[6366] D: Checking whether to break on /volume1/st/st4/index.php:4
[6366] D: I: Current location: /volume1/st/st4/index.php:1
[6366] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:4' against location '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:1'
[6366] D: R: Line number (1) doesn't match with breakpoint (4)
[6366] D: Checking whether to break on /volume1/st/st4/index.php:10
[6366] D: I: Current location: /volume1/st/st4/index.php:1
[6366] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:10' against location '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:1'
[6366] D: R: Line number (1) doesn't match with breakpoint (10)
[6366] D: Checking whether to break on /volume1/st/st4/index.php:4
[6366] D: I: Current location: /volume1/st/st4/index.php:3
[6366] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:4' against location '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:3'
[6366] D: R: Line number (3) doesn't match with breakpoint (4)
[6366] D: Checking whether to break on /volume1/st/st4/index.php:10
[6366] D: I: Current location: /volume1/st/st4/index.php:3
[6366] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:10' against location '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:3'
[6366] D: R: Line number (3) doesn't match with breakpoint (10)
[6366] D: Checking whether to break on /volume1/st/st4/index.php:4
[6366] D: I: Current location: /volume1/st/st4/index.php:4
[6366] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:4' against location '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:4'
[6366] D: F: File names match (/volume1/st/st4/index.php)
[6366] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="11" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///volume1/st/st4/index.php" lineno="4"></xdebug:message></response>

[6366] <- stack_get -i 12
[6366] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="12"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///volume1/st/st4/index.php" lineno="4"></stack></response>

[6366] <- context_names -i 13 -d 0
[6366] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_names" transaction_id="13"><context name="Locals" id="0"></context><context name="Superglobals" id="1"></context><context name="User defined constants" id="2"></context></response>

[6366] <- context_get -i 14 -d 0 -c 0
[6366] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_get" transaction_id="14" context="0"><property name="$i" fullname="$i" type="int"><![CDATA[1]]></property></response>

[6366] <- run -i 15
[6366] D: Checking whether to break on /volume1/st/st4/index.php:4
[6366] D: I: Current location: /volume1/st/st4/index.php:5
[6366] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:4' against location '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:5'
[6366] D: R: Line number (5) doesn't match with breakpoint (4)
[6366] D: Checking whether to break on /volume1/st/st4/index.php:10
[6366] D: I: Current location: /volume1/st/st4/index.php:5
[6366] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:10' against location '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:5'
[6366] D: R: Line number (5) doesn't match with breakpoint (10)
[6366] D: Checking whether to break on /volume1/st/st4/index.php:4
[6366] D: I: Current location: /volume1/st/st4/index.php:6
[6366] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:4' against location '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:6'
[6366] D: R: Line number (6) doesn't match with breakpoint (4)
[6366] D: Checking whether to break on /volume1/st/st4/index.php:10
[6366] D: I: Current location: /volume1/st/st4/index.php:6
[6366] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:10' against location '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:6'
[6366] D: R: Line number (6) doesn't match with breakpoint (10)
[6366] D: Checking whether to break on /volume1/st/st4/index.php:4
[6366] D: I: Current location: /volume1/st/st4/index.php:7
[6366] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:4' against location '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:7'
[6366] D: R: Line number (7) doesn't match with breakpoint (4)
[6366] D: Checking whether to break on /volume1/st/st4/index.php:10
[6366] D: I: Current location: /volume1/st/st4/index.php:7
[6366] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:10' against location '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:7'
[6366] D: R: Line number (7) doesn't match with breakpoint (10)
[6366] D: Checking whether to break on /volume1/st/st4/index.php:4
[6366] D: I: Current location: /volume1/st/st4/index.php:8
[6366] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:4' against location '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:8'
[6366] D: R: Line number (8) doesn't match with breakpoint (4)
[6366] D: Checking whether to break on /volume1/st/st4/index.php:10
[6366] D: I: Current location: /volume1/st/st4/index.php:8
[6366] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:10' against location '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:8'
[6366] D: R: Line number (8) doesn't match with breakpoint (10)
[6366] D: Checking whether to break on /volume1/st/st4/index.php:4
[6366] D: I: Current location: /volume1/st/st4/index.php:9
[6366] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:4' against location '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:9'
[6366] D: R: Line number (9) doesn't match with breakpoint (4)
[6366] D: Checking whether to break on /volume1/st/st4/index.php:10
[6366] D: I: Current location: /volume1/st/st4/index.php:9
[6366] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:10' against location '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:9'
[6366] D: R: Line number (9) doesn't match with breakpoint (10)
[6366] D: Checking whether to break on /volume1/st/st4/index.php:4
[6366] D: I: Current location: /volume1/st/st4/index.php:10
[6366] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:4' against location '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:10'
[6366] D: R: Line number (10) doesn't match with breakpoint (4)
[6366] D: Checking whether to break on /volume1/st/st4/index.php:10
[6366] D: I: Current location: /volume1/st/st4/index.php:10
[6366] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:10' against location '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:10'
[6366] D: F: File names match (/volume1/st/st4/index.php)
[6366] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="15" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///volume1/st/st4/index.php" lineno="10"></xdebug:message></response>

[6366] <- stack_get -i 16
[6366] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="16"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///volume1/st/st4/index.php" lineno="10"></stack></response>

[6366] <- stack_get -i 17
[6366] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="17"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///volume1/st/st4/index.php" lineno="10"></stack></response>

[6366] <- context_names -i 18 -d 0
[6366] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_names" transaction_id="18"><context name="Locals" id="0"></context><context name="Superglobals" id="1"></context><context name="User defined constants" id="2"></context></response>

[6366] <- context_get -i 19 -d 0 -c 0
[6366] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_get" transaction_id="19" context="0"><property name="$i" fullname="$i" type="int"><![CDATA[4]]></property></response>

[6366] <- run -i 20
[6366] D: Checking whether to break on /volume1/st/st4/index.php:4
[6366] D: I: Current location: /volume1/st/st4/index.php:11
[6366] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:4' against location '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:11'
[6366] D: R: Line number (11) doesn't match with breakpoint (4)
[6366] D: Checking whether to break on /volume1/st/st4/index.php:10
[6366] D: I: Current location: /volume1/st/st4/index.php:11
[6366] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:10' against location '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:11'
[6366] D: R: Line number (11) doesn't match with breakpoint (10)
[6366] D: Checking whether to break on /volume1/st/st4/index.php:4
[6366] D: I: Current location: /volume1/st/st4/index.php:12
[6366] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:4' against location '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:12'
[6366] D: R: Line number (12) doesn't match with breakpoint (4)
[6366] D: Checking whether to break on /volume1/st/st4/index.php:10
[6366] D: I: Current location: /volume1/st/st4/index.php:12
[6366] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:10' against location '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:12'
[6366] D: R: Line number (12) doesn't match with breakpoint (10)
[6366] D: Checking whether to break on /volume1/st/st4/index.php:4
[6366] D: I: Current location: /volume1/st/st4/index.php:16
[6366] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:4' against location '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:16'
[6366] D: R: Line number (16) doesn't match with breakpoint (4)
[6366] D: Checking whether to break on /volume1/st/st4/index.php:10
[6366] D: I: Current location: /volume1/st/st4/index.php:16
[6366] D: I: Matching breakpoint '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:10' against location '/volume1/st/st4/index.php:16'
[6366] D: R: Line number (16) doesn't match with breakpoint (10)
[6366] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="20" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[6366] <- stop -i 21
[6366] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stop" transaction_id="21" status="stopped" reason="ok"></response>

[6366] Log closed at 2022-01-26 19:43:33
```

Comment: *"‚Debugger for Firefox‘ doesn’t stop at breakpoints"* Just in case: "Debugger for Firefox" is for JavaScript debug and not PHP... And PHP Debugger (when debugging a web page) works with ANY browser -- the request can even be sent from Postman, curl etc.

Comment: 1) I suggest you enable Xdebug log, try to debug and see what it has to say (where it tries to debug (if at all), and what the response would be. That's the starting point. 2) I also suggest you double check your Xdebug LIVE config values (whole Xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output) when debugging a web page -- there is always a chance that web server will use different php.ini/config file than a CLI does (at very least it's quite common on Linux and Mac these days).

Comment: Thank you very much, LazyOne, for your quick answer and for reformatting my question. On my NAS I set "xdebug.remote_log" to my log file path and "xdebug.remote_log_level" to "10".
In the log the local and the remote path to the index.php did not match.
So, in my "Listen for Debug" config I added a "pathMappings" property to resolve this. Now, when I start debugging and reload the page in the browser, breakpoints are hit and variable values are shown in VSCodium.

But the web page is still showing "1234" right from the beginning. Is this how it should be or can it still be optimized?

Comment: *"But the web page is still showing "1234" right from the beginning."* This could be a some kind of left-over from the previous page (previous invocation) that the browser shows. The page cannot show the final result before executing the actual code yet. You can test this my changing the starting number in `$i = 1;` to lets say `2` or `3` to have a different final result. Or perhaps your page is executed twice somehow: the first run shows the page and the 2nd gets debugger attention... (no idea how this may work though.... just a weird idea).

Comment: Thanks again! I added the output of my Xdebug log to my question, but I cannot find any suspicious output there. I tried changing the index.php, setting $i to any other number, but when reloading the web page while debugging it is still showing the previous version of the page in Firefox and the loading indicator is shown in the browser tab. Only when debugging is done (i.e. all breakpoints were hit and the debugger has stopped on the last line) Firefox finishes reloading the page and is showing the new version of the page (e.g. "12345").

Comment: *"Only when debugging is done Firefox finishes reloading the page and is showing the new version of the page (e.g. "12345")."* Yes, I see the same. It's expected. When you are on a some site (e.g. here on SO) and click some link (e.g. another question) the browser does not render an empty page -- it awaits the response/content from the server first. Only then it starts doing based on the response -- a redirect or parse & render the page.

Comment: If you are asking "I have `echo $i;` so I'm expecting to see `1` and then `12` and then `123` on the page while I step through the script step by step"... It doe snot really work like that. Simply because the web server (and PHP first of all) buffers the response until it gets large enough. That's for optimisation purposes. Esp if compression is needed etc.

Comment: OK, I understand. Then everything seems to be working as it should. Your tip about enabling the Xdebug log file and the explanation about buffering when loading the PHP pages were the most helpful. I would like to upvote these or mark them as an accepted answer, but as a new user I seem to lack the reputation to do so. So thank you!

Comment: I had the same problem: VSCodium 1.66.0 with 'Debugger for Firefox' extn wouldn't stop at breakpoints - they were greyed out 'Unverified Breakpoint'.  The extension 'Details' page shows [v2.9.6 (Dec-2021)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=firefox-devtools.vscode-firefox-debug) in the main text - but that's false - top of page shows [v2.9.1 (< Feb-2021)](https://open-vsx.org/extension/firefox-devtools/vscode-firefox-debug) which has bugs.  Either [switch repository](https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/blob/master/DOCS.md#how-to-use-the-vs-code-marketplace) or use VS Code.